# Envio de e-mail para múltiplos destinatários

Tags: php, html

Estou usando o sendmail, o problema e o seguinte.
Uso checkbox para marcar os destinatários. Como faço para que quando eu marcar as checkbox ele preencha uma variável com cada destinatário, a virgula e o próximo destinatário?

```
input type="checkbox" name="todos" class="todos" onclick="marcardesmarcar()" /> Todos<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="marcar" name="email1"  value="email@email.comr" /> email1 (email@email.com)<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="marcar" name="email2"  value="email@email.com" /> email2 (email@email.com)<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="marcar" name="email3"  value="email@email.com" /> email3 (email@email.com)<br>
```

Variavel que vai receber no php:

`$email = $_POST["email"];`

Após feito a validação e preenchido o corpo. Envia:

`mail($email,$assunto,$mensagem, $headers, "-r".$email_from);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resolver seu problema assim:

```js
        var inputs = $('input[name="email[]"]');
        inputs.on('change', function () {
            var str = [];
            var control = 0;
            inputs.each(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    str.push(this.value);
                  control++;
                }
            });
            $('input[name="emails"]').val(str.join(', '));
        });
```

```css
#out{width:600px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="email[]" value="email1@email1.com1">email1@email1.com1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="email[]" value="email2@email2.com2">email2@email2.com2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="email[]" value="email3@email3.com3">email3@email3.com3
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="emails" value="" id="out">
```

Comment: Porque a id out?

Comment: Para não aparecer a input texto vou atribuir um hidden nela. Vou fazer um teste mais tarde. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: É apenas nomenclatura Willian. Você pode colocar o id que se enquadra no seu contexto. Se no seu sistema esse campo não for visível você pode esconde-lo também. Tudo vai das suas necessidades.

Comment: E que digo. Tem a necessidade de tê-lo com o tamanho de 600px? Não entendi ali. Tudo bem. Eu até tinha uma solução para esse caso. Mais o código fica grande com muita if else. Kkkk sou fraco com ajax. Mais pelo que vi ali vai dar na veia.

Comment: Não precisa ter 600px exatamente. Você pode deixar deixar 100% em seu container ou algo do tipo. Só coloquei 600px pra deixar visível os 3 email's.

Comment: Pra chamar o ajax não precisa de function não né? Nunca usei ele com JavaScript junto. Esses checkbox tem algumas funções pra habilita-los e marca-los.

Comment: Recomendo fortemente fazer uma função e chamar no evento que quiser.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando a [função mail()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php) do PHP você pode enviar para múltiplos destinatários fazendo o uso do primeiro parâmetro desta forma:

```
mail('exemplo1@email.com, exemplo2@email.com, ...', ...);
```

Basta dividir os emails dentro da string do primeiro parâmetro usando uma virgula(,).

Comment: Vou usar a  função mail com a variável dentro da string. Mais tenho a necessidade de enviar para múltiplos preenchendo a variável.